# Non-terminating RegExp.exec in Rhino

Tags: javascript, html, regex, rhino

I have the following JavaScript program saved in a file `pre.js`:

```
var pre = readFile("method-help.html");
RegExp.multiline = true;
print(/<pre>((?:.|\s)+)<\/pre>/.exec(pre)[1]);
```

The contents of `method-help.html` is simply the page at http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=answers/%7bid%7d.  What I'm trying to do is get the JSON code in between the `pre` tags.  However, when I run the program in Rhino, nothing is printed out and the program does not terminate.  The command I use is:

```
java -jar js.jar pre.js
```

My Rhino version is 1_7R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't seem to terminate is probably catastrophic back-tracking due to `.` and `\s` overlapping (it would end eventually, but it could be a long time).  Here's a correct, fast, version:

```
var pre = readFile("method-help.html");
print(/<pre>([\s\S]*?)<\/pre>/.exec(pre)[1])
```

You don't need `multiline`.  That only affects the meaning of `^` and `$`, which you're not using.  However, we do use `\s\S` to mean *all* characters (including newline, etc.).  We also use `*?` to mean zero or more characters, non-greedy.  The question mark (non-greedy) doesn't matter here but it would if there were multiple `pre` blocks.